# ReactNative New Architecture ViewManagerDelegate vs ViewManager receiveCommand

Tags: react-native

In react-native new architecture, properties and methods are mapped internally via Delegates generated from codegen.

Eg. the generated delegate code maps the 'mode' property to 'setMode' method in ViewManager.

**ViewManagerDelegate Code (codegen)**

```
  public void setProperty(T view, String propName, @Nullable Object value) {
    switch (propName) {
      case "mode":
        mViewManager.setMode(view, value == null ? null : (String) value);
```

And ViewManager class has to override the setMode method to use the mode value.

**ViewManager Code (manual)**

```
    @Override
    @ReactProp(name = "mode")
    public void setMode(SomeView view, @Nullable String mode) {
        Log.d("SomeView", "setMode ---- "+mode);
```

This pattern works for properties, but not for methods.

Eg. following is the generated code for a native method in delegate.

**ViewManagerDelegate Code (codegen)**

```
  @Override
  public void receiveCommand(T view, String commandName, ReadableArray args) {
    switch (commandName) {
      case "trigger":
        mViewManager.trigger(view, args.getString(0));
```

And here is the ViewManager class overriding the trigger method.

**ViewManager Code (manual)**

```
    @Override
    @ReactMethod
    public void trigger(SomeView view, String text) {
        Log.d("SomeView", "Native method triggered directly: "+text);
```

But this does not work and the only way to make it work is by overriding the receiveCommand directly in ViewManager class like so.

**ViewManager Code (manual)**

```
    @Override
    public void receiveCommand(@NonNull VisionCamera view, String commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
        mDelegate.receiveCommand(view, commandId, args);
```

I can't find any documentation explaining this?